# Change color of ScrollView indicator

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am trying to change the color of scroll indicator of ScrollView in react-native. 
If I use  this [prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#indicatorstyle)
on Android I will get an error, that indicatorStyle is not a valid property.
Now this is not suprising because it is described in documentation it is suppoerted only on iOS.

Now the question is, is there a way to change the color of indicator on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Create a xml scrollbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 


<gradient 
      android:angle="45" 
      android:endColor="#FF3401"    
      android:centerColor="#ff5c33" 
      android:startColor="#FF3401" /> 
      <corners android:radius="8dp" /> 

</shape>
```

and add this scroll bar like

`android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar`"

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try that, however  I was thinking something more on react-native level, not from the native code level. do you think it is possible?

Comment: I can't help you on this , im sorry mate